# Pulseaudio TCP streaming without avahi

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, streaming

I'm trying to streaming audio using PulseAudio but for some reasons (I can share them, but it's not important for this question) I don't want to install the `avahi-deamon` and `zero-conf` module and I don't have any X server.

In my "source" system I added this line to `/etc/pulse/system.pa`:load-module

```
module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/16 auth-anonymous=1
```

I'm running PA in system mode because it's an headless machine (RPi with Raspbian).

I can play anything with `paplay`.
Now on my desktop with Debian I want to receive the audio stream. All the stuff I find uses the Avahi deamon and `pavucontrol`.

Is there a way to manually connect from console without those services?
Of course I know the IP of the PA server.

I tried with:

```
parecord -r -s 192.168.1.195 -d alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono rec.wav
```

but I got:

> Stream error: No such entity

Comment: Have you tried creating a tunnel?  On your client, add 'load-module module-tunnel-sink-new server=192.168.1.195 sink_name=Remote channels=2 rate=44100' to your default.pa

Comment: Just tried, nothing has changed unfortunately.